# how to get a list of values?

Tags: java

Below is the code which i want to get the output of the names of the particular administrator number , administrator Emailid , but insted of that i am getting the output as : List of ---> com.demo.model.Administrator@91e143 with different numbers , basically i am new to java .Would you please help me in the Loop Iteration .

```
package com.demo.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.demo.model.Administrator;

import com.demo.model.AdministratorDAO;
import com.demo.model.AdministratorDemo;
import com.demo.model.JQueryDataTableParam;
import com.demo.model.JqueryDatatablesParamUtil;

public class AdministratorAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("in execute..");
        JQueryDataTableParam param = JqueryDatatablesParamUtil
                .getParam(request);


        String txt2=request.getParameter("txt1");
        //String select2=request.getParameter("select1");
        //request.setAttribute("e", "select2");

        //String select3=request.getParameter("select2");

        //System.out.println("txtValue->"+e);
        //System.out.println("txtValue->"+select2);
        System.out.println("txtValue->"+txt2);
        //String var = Administrator.isValidname(sData);
        String sEcho = param.sEcho;
        int iTotalRecords;
        int iTotalDisplayRecords;
        int start = param.iDisplayStart;
        System.out.println("start" + start);
        int last = param.iDisplayLength +param.iDisplayStart;
        System.out.println("last" + last);
        int sortColumnIndex = param.iSortColumnIndex;
        System.out.println("sortColumnIndex" + sortColumnIndex);
        String sortDirection = param.sSortDirection;
        System.out.println("sortDirection" + sortDirection);

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
        iTotalRecords = AdministratorDemo.getAdminCount();
        List<Administrator> Administrators = new LinkedList<Administrator>();
        for (Administrator a : AdministratorDemo.getAdimistrators()) {
            if (a.getAdministrator_nm() != null
                    && a.getAdministrator_nm().toLowerCase()
                            .contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase())

                    || a.getAdmin_Email_ID() != null
                    && a.getAdmin_Email_ID().toLowerCase()
                            .contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase())
                    || a.getAdmin_Fax_Phone_Num_Tx() != null
                    && a.getAdmin_Fax_Phone_Num_Tx().toLowerCase()
                            .contains(param.sSearch.toLowerCase())) {
                Administrators.add(a);

            }

        }
        iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalRecords;

    if (Administrators.size() < param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength)

                Administrators = Administrators.subList(param.iDisplayLength,
                        Administrators.size());
            else
                Administrators = Administrators.subList(param.iDisplayStart,
                        param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength);

        System.out.println("End of the operations");

        try {
            JSONObject jsonresponse = new JSONObject();
            jsonresponse.put("sEcho", sEcho);
            jsonresponse.put("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
            jsonresponse.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);
            JSONArray row = new JSONArray();

            for(Iterator<Administrator> i = AdministratorDemo.getAdimistrators().iterator();i.hasNext();)
            {
            System.out.println(i.next());
            }
            jsonresponse.put("aaData", data);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().print(jsonresponse.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.getWriter().print(e1.getMessage());
        }


        System.out.println("In execute method.");


        return null;

    }

    public String getXMLObject(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return new java.util.Date().toString()
                + " sent by vasu from Date Action";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a list of `Administrator`s, where you want to make a list of `String`s.
Alternatively (and probably better), if you can change the `Administrator` class, just implement the `toString` method in it, that will return the string you want to see on the screen.

Comment: it worked, and also how to place the value in the Json array :For example row.put(i.next()), its not working in the databale.Would you please in this task.

Answer (score 2):

The result that you are seeing (com.demo.model.Administrator@91e143) is the default string representation of the Administrator object, more specifically, it's what is returned by the default `toString()` method inherited from `Object`

To print useful information, override `public String toString()` of `Administrator`

Comment: In the Administrator Class -should i write public String to String

Comment: `public String toString() { return "a string that contains meaningful data about this instance of Administrator"; }`

Comment: it would be better to edit your post and add a sample about `toString()` method instead of putting it in a comment

Comment: IF u don't mind ,would you please provide an example is that i have get and set methods in the Administrator for Admin_Email id ,Admin_cd,Admin_phone

Comment: @user1257958 My answer has an example `toString()` implementation. You should be able to create your own based on this.

Comment: it worked, and also how to place the value in the Json array :For example row.put(i.next()), its not working in the databale.Would you please in this task

Answer (score 2):

You need to override [Object#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Map.html) in your `Administrator` class.

This method can return any meaningful representation of the object you want, e.g:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "id = " + id + "email = " + email;
}
```

Comment: it worked, and also how to place the value in the Json array :For example row.put(i.next()), its not working in the databale.Would you please in this task

Comment: @user1257958 You need to submit a new question. Also you should accept an answer you found helpful for this question, use the tick icon to the left of an answer.